# Why do these corner cases in Haskell's import-as work and what do they do?

Tags: haskell, import

I've come across some modules that contain particularly strange imports.

First of all, I have seen a module `A` that imports an other module as himself. For example:

```
-- module A.hs
module A where
import B as A   -- ???

f = id
```

What does this do? Why is the above permitted at all?

However what most troubles me is that the code is actually of this kind:

```
module A where
import B as A  -- Okay, assume this works...
import C as A  -- ??? A is already defined!

f = id
```

Why can more then one module be imported with the same name? What does this achieve?
I thought that these kind of `import`s weren't permitted and also [*A Gentle Introduction to Haskell*](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html) states that:

> it is illegal to import two different entities having the same name
>   into the same scope.

However these imports work fine. Yet an other strange thing that bugs me is exporting the module itself:

```
module A (module A) where
```

To summarize, given the following MWE:

```
-- A.hs
module A (module A) where
import B as A
import C as A

f = id

-- B.hs
module B where

g = id

-- C.hs
module C where

h = id
```

1. Are the imports following the standards or is this some bug of GHC? It doesn't look like a bug, but I can't find any reference that explains all these corner cases.
2. What's the exact result achieved? I mean: which names are imported and/or exported from `A`?

Comment: I've never seen exporting the module from itself; that's interesting.  All other cases, the names in the different imports are unioned.  E.g. 1st example: A.somethingInB refers to B's version, but A.f refers to A's version (unless B also defines f, then it's an ambiguity error).  Fortunately, this cleanly generalizes :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name qualifiers are not the same thing as module names. A name qualifier is just a collective scope, you can make it refer to any number of modules. Normally you won't add more than one, but in one case you *almost always* add plenty of modules: in the *unqualified scope*. `import Data.List` might be read as something like `import qualified Data.List as ""`: it arranges that, say, `sortBy` will be found when referring to it with an "empty qualifier", i.e. with none. But we could "rename" that scope:

```
module Main where

import qualified Prelude as P
import qualified Data.List as P
import qualified Data.Ord as P

main :: P.IO ()
main = do    -- `do` is syntax, not a name!
   P.print  P..  P.map  P.snd  P.$  P.sortBy  (P.comparing  P.fst)
     [(4,'o'),(6,' '),(0,'H'),(1,'e'),(3,'l'),(9,'r'),(7,'W'),(10,'l'),(8,'o'),(2,'l'),(5,','),(11,'d'),(12,'!')]
```

The only qualifiers that are fixed are the ones specific to the module in your file itself: that's always both in unqualified scope, and in the scope automatically named after the module. And for *definitions*, you must use the unqualified form.

For `module A (module A)`, that seems pretty much bogus. I don't think module exports are really well thought-through. They only work properly when you refer to an actual module, not just a name qualifier, i.e.

```
module PowerPrelude (module A)
import qualified Prelude as A
import qualified Data.List as A
import qualified Data.Ord as A
```

will *not* work. Which makes you wonder why it's allowed to declare such an export at all. Might indeed be a bug here.

Comment: It can be useful to explicitly export the entire current module, if for example you want to reexport some modules and the entire current module: `module A (module A; module B; module C) where; import B; import C; ...` If it weren't possible you would have to specify every single declaration in `A` in the exports.

Comment: Right. Though that doesn't explain why it's not an error to export a "module" scope that's not actually a module name – the `PowerPrelude` example compiles, only it doesn't expose anything!

Comment: In your last example you added a `qualified` that is not present in my case. In fact those names *are* exported in my code... what I don't get is the use-case. To me it seems like `module A (module A) where import B as A` is perfectly equivalent to `module A (module B) import B`, or isn't it?

Comment: @Bakuriu: `qualified` simply prevents that the names from that module can be used locally without a qualifier, otherwise it's the same as `import Bar as B`. — No: `module A (module A) where import B as A` does _not_ export `B`, only the local definitions in you module `A`. It so happens that there'll be also some other stuff in the _scope_ `A` coming from `B`, but that's not considered for the export.

Comment: That's not what I'm observing. If `B` defines `f` and `A` contains: `module A (module A) where import B as A` then in GHCi I **can** access `A.f`. If `A` contains: `module A where import B as A` then trying to access `A.f` raises a *not in scope* error. Is this a bug in GHC? or is it correct for `module A (module A)` to export also the imported names?

Comment: What you can do with the module _loaded_ in GHCi is irrelevant: that ignores the export list and gives you access to _everything_ the module itself has in scope. Try _importing_ the module.

Comment: I have just tried and indeed I **can** access `f` defined in `B` if I specify the `module A` in the export list. With `A`, `B` and `C` defined as in the question and `test.hs`: containing `import A;a=f;b=g;c=h;main = putStr "Hello, World!"`, compile with GHC and you wont get any error. Remove the `(module A)` from `A` and you'll get errors for `g` and `h`.